# is it possbiel to define pact to match the properties'type but not the value?

Tags: pact

when defining pact file, values of the request and the response are often variable. Say, we will have the data preparation before we create the pact. In thise case, the pact is never changed (ignore the values changes as they are always generated randomly).

How can we handle this scenario with pact?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are called matchers.

All languages support them, see https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/blob/master/README.md#matching for the js DSL.